# Setting up Scala Play testing with H2 in-memory database

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, h2

Play docs say "The H2 in memory database is very convenient for development because your evolutions are run from scratch when play is restarted." This is all I want. And here is what I have done so far (Play 2.5.6):

1. I created a testing configuration file to use H2 with evolutions, as follows:

   ```
   play.evolutions {
     db.default.enabled = true
     autoApply = true
   }

   db {
     default {
       driver = org.h2.Driver
       url = "jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=MYSQL;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"
       username = sa
       password = ""
       pool = "bonecp"   // otherwise you can't log your sql...
       bonecp.logStatements=true
     }
   }
   ```
2. I added a simple evolutions file "/conf/evolutions/default/1.sql":

   ```
   # --- !Ups

   CREATE TABLE PROJECTS (
     id int(11) NOT NULL
   ) ;

   # --- !Downs

   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PROJECTS;
   ```
3. My controller takes a database. This is where the test database should be injected instead of the MySQL one. It has a test action that reads a table:

   ```
   class DataManagementController @Inject()(db: Database) extends Controller {

         def test() = Action {
           db.withConnection { conn =>
             val st = conn.createStatement()
             val res = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM PROJECTS")
             while (res.next()) { println(res.getInt("id")) }
           }
           Ok("")
         }
   }
   ```
4. I wrote my first test of that action as follows:

   ```
   class ControllerSpec extends PlaySpec with OneAppPerSuite {

     val TestDb = Databases.inMemory("default")
     val dataCtrl = new DataManagementController(TestDb)

     "DataManagementController" should {
       "test" in {
         dataCtrl.test().apply(FakeRequest())
       }
     }
   }
   ```
5. When I run the test, I see evolutions getting applied to the H2 db, but at the time queries are run, everything got erased (?) despite the `DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1` option:

   ```
   ~ test-only ControllerSpec

   [info] ControllerSpec:
   [debug] c.j.b.BoneCPDataSource - JDBC URL = jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=MYSQL;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1, Username = sa, partitions = 1, max (per partition) = 30, min (per partition) = 5, idle max age = 10 min, idle test period = 1 min, strategy = DEFAULT
   [debug] c.j.b.StatementHandle - select id, hash, apply_script, revert_script, state, last_problem from play_evolutions where state like 'applying_%'
   [error] o.j.StatementLogger - java.sql.Statement.executeQuery: select id, hash, apply_script, revert_script, state, last_problem from play_evolutions where state like 'applying_%';
   throws exception: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "play_evolutions" not found; SQL statement:
   select id, hash, apply_script, revert_script, state, last_problem from play_evolutions where state like 'applying_%' [42102-192]
   [...]
   [debug] c.j.b.StatementHandle -
     create table play_evolutions (
   [...]
   [debug] c.j.b.StatementHandle - CREATE TABLE PROJECTS (
       id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       person_id int(11) NOT NULL,
       name varchar(255)  NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (id),
   )
   [debug] c.j.b.StatementHandle - update play_evolutions set state = 'applied' where id = 1
   [debug] c.j.b.StatementHandle - select id, hash, apply_script, revert_script, state, last_problem from play_evolutions where state like 'applying_%'

   [info] DataManagementController
   [info] application - Creating Pool for datasource 'default'
   [info] - should test *** FAILED ***
   [info]   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "PROJECTS" not found;
   [...]
   ```

   If I explore the database with `h2-browser` (url: "jdbc:h2:mem:test" + args), it is empty. But if I now modify "1.sql", I get

   ```
   Database 'default' is in an inconsistent state![An evolution has not been applied properly. Please check the problem and resolve it manually before marking it as resolved.]
   ```

   but it does not say how to resolve the problem (since I see an empty database in the browser).

I would greatly appreciate any help setting up a test database. I have seen many posts here asking similar questions, with either no answer or none accepted, several different approaches, and I literally have been trying for days. N.B. It would make a useful section in StackOverflow Docs (and Play docs btw).

Comment: Can also have a look at http://tour.acolyte.eu.org/

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked against Play 2.5, but I'd expect this to be pretty similar to the latest 2.4 versions.

It's important to understand the lifecyle of your components here. The way your test is set up, there's actually two H2 databases involved.

1. `test` is managed by PlaySpec according to the test configuration you are providing. This usually requires to use [`WithApplication`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaFunctionalTestingWithSpecs2#WithApplication). Here `DB_CLOSE_DELAY` is properly set.
2. You are running your tests against an H2 database `default` you've created yourself. `DB_CLOSE_DELAY` is not set for this instance, but you could provide a map of urlOptions:

   `Databases.inMemory("default", urlOptions = Map("DB_CLOSE_DELAY" -> "-1"))`

There's a couple of options (without trying to be complete):

1. Use a plain Specs2 specification rather than the PlaySpec. This way you avoid to have a fake Play app running in the background. But you won't benefit from Play's evolutions.

   Apply migrations / insert test fixtures using H2 and the url option `INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:evolutions/default/1.sql'`
2. Point the database in your spec against `test` rather than `default` to make sure you are connecting to the same database and use [`WithApplication`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaFunctionalTestingWithSpecs2#WithApplication) to let Play manage it.
3. Instead of instantiating your controller in the test, you can also let Play's router do it and call the action. Checkout the documentation [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaFunctionalTestingWithSpecs2#Testing-the-router).

Comment: Thanks, it helps a lot. Should I give up having 2 settings files, then? I don't get if the test database should be defined in the config file, in a fake application, with some Guice override, or instantiated directly like I do. I really don't need options, but a single best way to have a test database once and for all my future apps, making use of the dependency injection.

Comment: It's hard to give a clear recommendation, there's so many pros and cons.
Using `WithApplication` is certainly simple and brings the convenience that Play will wire your app. However, you're limited to one database / and hence also one Play app at a time. So you cannot run your tests in parallel as you cannot isolate them and they might conflict.
Personally, to me that's a bummer, but for a tiny app it might not be a big issue. If you are looking for a quick way, I'd suggest keeping the test configuration and giving 3) a try. Checkout the link to the documentation, that's quite helpful...

Comment: Thanks. I read those links so many times. Option 3 means creating a fake implicit `app` somehow (I have no clue how to inject my db into that template, although I tried with Guice overcomplicated stuff for hours, posted a question on SO and got no answer), and they themselves say in the documentation that creating a whole Application instance for every test/suite is not good.

Comment: I think I understood what you meant about test config file + option 3. It is probably best after all.

Comment: Sorry, didn't manage to get back here to you yesterday again. Awesome! The clue really is that there's no need to inject the test db as it's already configured to use H2 and play will set it up for you.